# How to do i find touch up counts on one location

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am loading textfields dynamically in uitableview in want to faind touch up counts on each text field because i have to appear keyboard for second touch on that particular text field like each text field and i have setted tags for each textfield here i can resign textfield for second touch

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self.playerTable.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx,BOOL*stop)
         {
             UITableViewCell *cell = obj;

             if([cell isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
             {
                 for(UITextField *textField in cell.contentView.subviews)
                 {
                     if([textField isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
                     {
                         if ([textField isFirstResponder])
                         {
                             [textField resignFirstResponder];
                          }
                      }
                 }
               }
             }
    ];

}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
   [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: I am not getting your question properly... Can you explain it with an example?

Comment: i am loading textfields dynamivally in uitableview when i click on textfield dont appear keyboard then again click on textfield keyboard has to appear so secon click only key board has to be appear thanks for take a look

Comment: @BoosaRamesh like a double click? or it could be two clicks in different moments?

Comment: doubleclick on each text field one click for resign and another for become

Comment: i am editing all text fields in tableview so for that purpose i have to maintain keybaord allow for second click only not open staright away

Answer (score 1):

trying to resign and then calling becomeFirstResponder, I think it is not the best way to do it, even more when you have the UITableView.

I propose two solutions:

1. You must have to double tap the cell to call `[UITextField becomeFirstResponder]`:

Create your own `UITableViewCell` that have a textField inside of the cell view, for the example we will call it `TextFieldCell`

On tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method, create a tapGesture and add it to the cell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    TextFieldCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"textFieldCellID"];

    cell.textField.userInteractionEnabled = NO; // Disable the interaction for textField doesn't catch the tap
    cell.textField.delegate = self;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(becomeFirstResponderOnSelectedTextField:)];
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2; // Number of taps required to call becomeFirstResponderOnSelectedTextField:
    tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1; // Number of fingers that you need to use to "active" the gesture

    [cell addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

return cell;

}
```

When you double tap the cell

```
-(void)becomeFirstResponderOnSelectedTextField:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGesture
{

    TextFieldCell *cell = (TextFieldCell *)tapGesture.view;
    cell.textField.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [cell.textField becomeFirstResponder];

}
```

To restore the `userInteraction` property of the textField:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    textField.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}
```

2.The cell must be selected to edit the text in the textField:

As the previous section, create your own cell, disable the `userInteraction` property of the `TextField` but, in this case, don't add a gesture to the cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    TextFieldCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"textFieldCellID"];
    cell.textField.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    return cell;

}
```

When you select the cell, enable the `userInteraction` property:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    TextFieldCell *cell = (TextFieldCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textField.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}
```

So you can tap again on the cell whenever you want to edit your `textField`.

To restore the `userInteraction` property and hide the keyboard:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    TextFieldCell *cell = (TextFieldCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.textField resignFirstResponder];
    cell.textField.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    return indexPath;
}
```

If you want to stay in the textField until the user type something, add this line in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
// Each time you type, textFieldTextChange: will be called
[cell.textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldTextChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

and these two methods:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

    // Blocks every cell, but not the current cell
    for (TextFieldCell *cell in self.tableView.visibleCells) {
        if (cell.textField.isFirstResponder) continue;
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }

}

- (void)textFieldTextChanged:(id)sender
{
    // If there some text, unblocks all the cells, otherwise blocks all the cells, but not the current cell
    if ([(UITextField *)sender text].length > 0) {
            for (UITableViewCell *cell in self.tableView.visibleCells) {
            cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        }
    } else { 
        for (TextFieldCell *cell in self.tableView.visibleCells) {
            if (cell.textField.isFirstResponder) continue;
            cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: and one more doubt i dont want allow to go another textfield without entering the text in current text textfield what should i do can you tell me and current textfield should be select state

Comment: i have implemented above answer its working for me well thank you so much

Comment: hello soto actually i am maintaining tableview with textfields these are dynamically loded with some names when i edit and enter another name which is already existed in table view i have given one alert called " you have enterd same name " like in that situation i dont want to allow user to go and select another row until entering the different name. your answer is working well for me can you help me on this

Comment: Hi @BoosaRamesh, sure :) where or how are you saving your data??

Comment: in core data i am testing like  if([playerNameForEdit length] > 0){
   NSMutableArray *playerinfoArry = [dbWrapper getPlayerInfo];                         for (Playerinfo *player in playerinfoArry){
  if ([player.playername isEqualToString:playerNameForEdit])
    {   playerNameForEdit = @"";
          isPlayerExist = YES;
  CustomAlert *alert = [[CustomAlert alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Please choose a different name" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitle:@""];
  [alert showInView:self.view];}}}

Comment: if i enter different name in that situation alert is going to be appear forget to tell you this above code i have wrote in didselectrowAtIndexPath:

Comment: where do i have to put alert to check i mean in which method

Comment: check your chat messages

Answer (score 0):

Make a object variable of UITextField (txtActive) in .h file only for reference (do not alloc it.) and use this method... It will always appear keyboard at second time...

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == txtActive)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        [txtActive resignFirstResponder];
    }
    txtActive = textField;

    return FALSE;
}
```